# get longest string in jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgresql `jsonb` column that hold a bunch of demographic data, something like

```
{'city':'Mesa','county':'Maricopa'}
```

Is there an efficient way to get the longest county name in the database? I'm doing something like this currently, but I have tens of millions of rows and I'd like to make sure I'm not missing a faster way:

```
SELECT max(length(my_json_column->>'county'))
FROM demographics
```

Comment: Does the current query work? I just fail to see why a query like this would be executed very often but maybe that is none of my business.

Comment: it works, I just think it is probably slower than it could be. Thanks

Comment: If performance is crucial here, you can add a column with the length and add an index for it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). But I would not do that until this query becomes a real bottleneck.